# Having same route require and not authentication?

Tags: rest, api-design, restful-authentication

I have doubt regarding my RESTful or general API solution.

So, the case is that I need to serve same resource but in public and private manner. Meaning, that *GET api/products?private=true* will return products owned by current user and require authentication, and *GET api/products?private=true* will return all products without authentication.

I understand that this is bad practice, but would like to hear your opinion.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since `/api/products?private=true` and `/api/products?private=false` are distinct urls, there is nothing wrong from an HTTP perspective that these two endpoints return different results.

I think generally query parameters are used as a 'modifier' on the resource. So if you have a resource that returns products, and you have a query parameter that filters this list to return a subset, I would say that that is fairly common.

As an alternative you might consider to use something like `/products` and `/my-products` to create 2 endpoints that are more distinct.

Comment: Sure. Now I realised that my question was not clear enought. 
I meant to ask is it bad practice to have same route (/products), be public (meaning, it do not require authentication) and private (it does require authentication), depending or query parameter.

Comment: @djoloho HTTP doesn't have a concept of route, just urls and paths. Different urls can have different authentication requirements, so no I don't think there's anything wrong with this. Just be aware that once a client is authenticated, they will likely keep sending authentication information to your entire domain for every path.